Name of file saved through angular ui
In my angular application, there is a feature to download a file.
When the user clicks on the file download button, the "save as" window opens up, and the user can then set a name to that file, and save it.
I want to know the name of that file that user set.
I know that the full path can not be retrived as mentioned in this -> Get browser download path with javascript, and i don't need the full path, I just need the file name.
update: I want to know the name of file in the .ts(component) file, and show that name in a label tag in the html file.
Is there any way?

Can you please provide a bit more detail, like where you want to know the name of file?

Pretty sure that won't be possible. This is a privacy issue.

@ParthSavaliya I updated the question, did that answer your question?

@CBroe I think it may be possible with FIle System API (maybe)

@user448477 I mean some code snippet or something?

I solved the problem i created by using File System API
See the below code for reference
public async buttonClick() {
      try {
        const fileHandle = await this.getNewFileHandle();
        if (fileHandle) {
          console.log("after calling getNewFileHandle()");
          console.log(fileHandle.name);  // Got the filename here
          this.filename = fileHandle.name;
        }
      } catch (error) {
        if (error instanceof DOMException) {
          switch (error.name) {
            case 'NotAllowedError':
              console.error("Permission was denied.");
              break;
            case 'AbortError':
              console.error("The operation was aborted.");
              break;
            case 'SecurityError':
              console.error("Security error occurred.");
              break;
            case 'TypeError':
              console.error("Invalid options were provided.");
              break;
            default:
              console.error("An unknown DOMException occurred:", error);
          }
        } else {
          console.error("An unknown error occurred:", error);
        }
      }
    }
    
    getNewFileHandle() {
      let opts={};
      if ('showSaveFilePicker' in window) {
        opts = {
          types: [
            {
              description: 'Text file',
              accept: { 'text/plain': ['.txt'] },
            },
          ],
        };
        return window.showSaveFilePicker(opts);
      }
     else{}
    }

